# if data[3] > max(max_life): TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
import math

welcome = "welcome to the life expectancy data sheet"
print(welcome.upper())



with open("life-expectancy.csv") as data_set:
    for data in data_set:
        data = data.replace(",","                    ")
        print(data.strip())


        entity = data[0]
        code = data[1]
        year = data[2]
        life_expectancy = [3]

        year_lookup = int(input("Enter the of interest: "))

        max_life = max(data[3])
        min_life = min(data[3])

        # avg_value = sum(data[3]) / len(data[3])

        max_life = 0
        if data[3] > max(max_life):
            max_year = data[0]
            max_country = data[2]
        print(f"The overall max life expectancy is:{max_life} from {max_country} in {max_year}.")


        min_data = 0
        if data[3] > min(min_life):
            min_year = data[0]
            min_country = data[2]
        print(f"The overall max life expectancy is:{min_life} from {min_country} in {min_year}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You already took the max_life as max(data[3]), and then you set it to 0, but anyways you are trying to take the max of an int:

```
max_life = max(data[3])
max_life = 0
if data[3] > max(max_life):  # max of an int max_life does not work
```